# What is JAA/JAD

Tags: java

This was listed under a "solution manager" job posting: "Demonstrable understanding of JAA/JAD."

I've tried googling it, and it seems to point to a java decompiler, but knowledge of a java decompiler doesn't go with the rest of job description.

Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks

someone may want to add the correct tags as well, b/c I have no idea what tags to use.

Comment: Maybe it is a solution to "Oh crap, we lost the code!".  ;)

Comment: Maybe it is a test: "If he says he has experience with JAA/JAD, show him the door."

Comment: Maybe it is a food: "Jaa is the staple food of Newars. It is boiled rice eaten with lentils, vegetables and curry."

Comment: Ironically, the only thing I could Google up was a job listing for MicroSoft, posted on a dozen or so different job sites…  “Familiarity with techniques such as use case analysis, data / process flow diagramming, JAA / JAD, etc.” I wonder if that were meant to read “Java/RAD” ?

Comment: probably HR thought it was a good idea to acronymize everything that sounded barely technical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Joint Application Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_application_design).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Java Application Architecture/Java Application Development?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as Java Application Architecture/Design/Development?